# Como comparar variáveis usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparação

Utilizo muito comparação de variáveis. Exemplo:

```
 if (item[l].item[0] == 'tipoRescisao') {
                log.info('Tipo Rescisão: ' + item[l].item[1])
                if (
                    (item[l].item[1] == (1))
                        || (item[l].item[1] == 01)
                        || (item[l].item[1] == 08)
                        || (item[l].item[1] == 10)
                        || (item[l].item[1] == 12)
                        || (item[l].item[1] == 13)
                    ) {
                    prazo = dataDesligamento + 24;
                }
            }
```

Existe uma outra forma de realizar essas comparações de forma mais sucinta?

Comment: O que especificamente quer saber, se dá para comparar a variável com múltiplos valores?

Comment: isso mesmo, quero saber se uma variável está em determinada faixa de valores.

Comment: Tem dois q é o mesmo valor, tem algum motivo para isso?

Comment: Não, pode ignorar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode fazer esse tipo de verificação mais simples usando `indexOf`.

primeiramente crie um `array` como todas as possibilidades que deseja.

```
['1', '01', '08', '10', '12', '13']
```

Após basta verificar se o valor que busca esta dentro deste `array` através no `indexOf`

```
['1', '01', '08', '10', '12', '13'].indexOf(item[l].item[1])
```

Se o resultado encontrado for `-1` então o valor não existe no `array` de pesquisa.

Assim seu `if` ficaria :

```js
// Função simples
function inArray(value, array){
  return array.indexOf(value) != -1;
}

console.log(inArray('01', ['01', '10']));

// Aplicada ao prototype de string
String.prototype.inArray = function(array){
  return inArray(this.toString(), array);
}

console.log('01'.inArray(['01', '10']));
```

Comment: Consegue me ajudar na criação de uma função, já que utilizo muito essas comparações?

Comment: @durtto seja agora, se facilita um pouco.

Comment: +1 Se o resultado encontrado for -1 então o valor não existe no array de pesquisa

Answer (score 6):

Acredito que a forma mais fácil seria pesquisando em um *array* dos valores a serem comparados. Se ele achar no *array* é porque a variável vale pelo menos um desses valores. Tem gente que até tem alguma função para abstrair isso.

```
if ([1, 8, 10, 12, 13].indexOf(item[l].item[1]) > -1) {
    prazo = 20;
}
```

```js
var prazo = 0;
var x = 8;
if ([1, 8, 10, 12, 13].indexOf(x) > -1) prazo = 20;
console.log(prazo);
var prazo = 0;
var x = 7;
if ([1, 8, 10, 12, 13].indexOf(x) > -1) prazo = 20;
console.log(prazo);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Array/IndexOf.js).

Comment: hehe pensamos igual, mas eu demorei 2min  a mais :D

Answer (score -1):

Terá que verificar qual o tipo do valor `item[l].item[1]`.

Type *string*:
se for "01", terá que fazer desta forma

```
if(valor item[l].item[1] === "01")...
```

Type *Int*:
se for 1, terá que fazer desta forma

```
if(valor item[l].item[1] === 1)...
```

Comment: Sua resposta não me ajuda, não responde a pergunta.